# Bootstrap carousel ignoring data-interval attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-pause="hover">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div style="height:200px;">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="height:200px;">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <div style="height:200px;">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap v3.0.3, and yet the carousel still starts scrolling after page is loaded. I have also tried including:

```
$(function () {
    $(".carousel").carousel({ interval: false });
});
```

I've done this with and without the `data-interval` attribute, all to no avail. The carousel automatically starts scrolling after page is loaded. I have seen other questions about this but they were all referring to older version and implied it has been fixed by now.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Seems to work fine on 3.0.3 - http://bootply.com/103352 Do you have any other JavaScript code or other carousels on the same page?

Comment: You are absolutely right! There were some scripts for other plugins referenced before my script. They were leftovers from another site I built some time ago. The perils of copy'n'paste! It works just fine thanks :) What's the common practice here? I can't vote your comment as an answer. Do I just delete this question?

Comment: I added my comment as an solution/answer. Pls accept so that others know your question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your carousel markup is correct for 3.0.3 (http://bootply.com/103352)

Make sure there is not other JavaScript code or other carousels on the same page.