# Why is Bootstrap 3 carousel ignoring "data-interval" attribute in Rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

The question was asked before on Stackoverflow here: [Bootstrap carousel ignoring data-interval attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873278/bootstrap-carousel-ignoring-data-interval-attribute)

But the answer was not relevant in my case.

As stated in the title the data-interval attribute does not change the time each slide lingers in the carousel. at the moment it is too fast.  I have searched for where this is coming from in the CSS, but I cannot see anything related to the interval time. Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill"><%= image_tag "Acu.png"%></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" ><%= image_tag "terapia-nut.png"%></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" ></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">


.
.
.
.
.
.
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1000 //changes the speed
  })
});
</script>
```

CSS for carousel

```
/* Home Page Carousel */

header.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What other possible causes of this could there be?

Where can I see the raw bootstrap 3 CSS files in order to know what classes are controlling what attributes? Because they are hidden I often find it hard to know which classes and which attributes to change in order to control the CSS.

Comment: define header as: <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >

Comment: @Eugen that is how it was originally i just added the data-interval attribute in order to increase the time each slide lingers. it had no effect.